# Using Anderson Darling test statistic vs p value to infer Goodness of Fit

Tags: distributions, anderson-darling-test

I have been reading articles recently that discourage the use of p value for hypothesis testing (https://www.sciencenews.org/blog/context/experts-issue-warning-problems-p-values)

Rather than using a p-value from an AD Gof test I'd like to get some thoughts on how best to use the AD test statistic instead.

Rather than fit a bunch of distributions to my data and then pick the lowest AD test statistic (just because it's the lowest). Is there a range of critical values for AD statistic that should be used as a rule of thumb?

I'm aware there are tables of AD test statistics published for distinct distributions. I'm wondering if these tables should be used as the first point of reference?

Thanks in advance for any responses.
Jonathan

Comment: You should not use p-vales as a measure of closeness.

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for the clarification there. I'm wondering if the AD test statistic (ADTS) can be used instead of how can one determine what values of the ADTS can be used to infer GoF say for Log-Normal, Paretto etc. Are there tables available that contain ADTS values, that can be used for Goodness of fir assessment or is there a preferred criterion?